# How to devlop the apps for automotive android

Tags: android, android-emulator, automotive, android-automotive

I am trying to build simple apps for automotive android (not android auto),But I don't find the proper emulator to test it ?
So how to test these apps ?
Is there any emulator to downlaod ?
Is it possible to build it from source ? If it is possible to build from source, what would be the size of complete source? I try to checkout the source, but it downloaded more than 15 GB.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an emulator for Android Automotive available in Android Studio. You might need the most recent version of Android Studio to run it, but it should be available in the list under "Automotive". There should be a generic image and a Polestar 2 image. More info here if you don't see the Polestar 2 image: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#system-images

[image: A list of Android emulator images]